# sharepoint online quick launch

Tags: sharepoint, view, launch

we are converting from sharepoint 2003 to sharepoint on line.

I am having trouble reproducing a specific behavior in the online version.

If a choose a list, I get a "select a view" navigation on the left hand side of the page showing the available views.  When a new view is created, it automatically appears on this navigation list.

In the online sharepoint, instead there is a view dropdown.

I know I can manually setup links on the quick launch but I'm looking for an automatic way to do this.

Can the online sharepoint be set up so that when views are added they automatically appear as left-hand links?  Or can the "views" dropdown be moved to the left side which would be an acceptable work around?

Please note I am unfamiliar with SP designer and I do work with .NET but I dont want to go that route just for this issue - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just so i understand you correctly, you want to do something like this:

[image]

Where each of the quick launch links are links to a view?

And you want to do this without using sharepoint designer, or custom code?

I dont think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The view selector is a dropdown from version 2007 already, there is no list specific quicklaunch either, the quicklaunch is for current nav and site wide "quick" navigation. In sp2010 the list related actions are all included in the ribbon.